# Function that replace data with average of a column in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

**I want to write a function which takes the dataframe and the name of a column as parameters and replaces the empty values of the column entered by the average.
But when I execute it nothing happens, my null values are not replaced.**
Can you please help me to fix this.

Here is my code:

```
def function(data,col):
    col = col.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Comment: If `x` is `NaN` what is its `mean()`?

Comment: I tried also : `col = col.fillna(col.mean())` but it doesnt work